# Call Dialog from function [Android Studio]

Tags: java, android

Did someone know how I can call a dialog from function and if it's possible, because I've already try and this is return to me :

```
W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread Thread[AsyncTask #1,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow you are not calling Dialog from the main thread, can you post some code? Take a look here [Showing dialog from background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199014/show-an-alertdialog-from-a-background-thread-with-the-appcontext)

Comment: Thanks a lot i reach my goal

Comment: Great happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Showing a dialog means updating the UI, but you can't do it from a background thread.  
 Show the dialog in `onPostExecute()`